# Python local scope confusion

Tags: python, scope

I'm trying to understand Python scopes. See this example:

```
x = 'foo'

def outer(p):
    print x
    x = 'bar'
    def inner(p):
        print x
    inner(1)

print x
outer(1)
```

This code results the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scopes2.py", line 11, in <module>
    outer(1)
  File "scopes2.py", line 4, in outer
    print x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Now if I remove the `x = 'bar'` line, then it runs as expected.

How come I cannot use the global `x` from the `print x` in `outer()` until I rebind it to `'bar'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you have an assignment in a function, that variable is considered local for the entirety of the function. You can't just reference the global "until the local assignment"

---

[What are the rules for local and global variables in Python](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) (emphasis mine)

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. **If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere
>   within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local.** If a variable
>   is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is
>   implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains
>   this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a
>   bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was
>   required for all global references, you’d be using global all the
>   time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in
>   function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would
>   defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying
>   side-effects.

Comment: Does that mean that the interpreter doesn't process the code line-by-line during the execution then? I tried to put in an if 1: pass` `else: x='bar'\ndo_error` into the `outer()` function. Although execution would never reach the else branch, it still complained about the undefined local variable. On the other hand it didn't complain at all about the undefined `do_error`, and run perfectly if I removed the assignment.

Comment: Yes, the interpreter evaluates the entire function to determine global vs local

Comment: if `locals()` also doesn't contain the name `x` before the line `x = 'bar'`, is there a way to "find" it at that point? I mean to find that such a name might be bonded in the block?

Comment: @Mkoch (1 comment up) yes, but that's a matter for a separate question, if you're still curious about it - and not really recommended. A better solution is to just use a different name for the local variable. (3 comments up) this happens because Python is _compiled_ to bytecode and then interpreted, not interpreted directly from the source code. The compiler processes the whole function definition at once and creates a symbol table (name->memory location) for that entire function.

Comment: @mhlester This thread is pretty old, hopefully, someone responds. So the way interpreter works is that it takes up a function checks its validity and execute line by line ? So in a huge python program, the syntax error in a function can be found only when interpreter reaches that particular function ?

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the the global `x` from the function, use

```
def outer(p):
    global x
    print x
    x = 'bar'
    ...
```

Note that the assignment to `x` would rebind the *global* `x` too. If you don't want to happen, rename one of the variables (or, better still, don't use global variables).

Comment: global is needed if I want to change the global x instead of rebinding it in my local scope, but this does not answer my question imho